# Error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7 (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting this error message while building the Cordova Android app.

> Error:(159, 66) error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source
>   1.7 (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)

[image]

The following compileOptions has been set on my build.gradle (module android) and build.gradle (module CordovaLib) as you can see here:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

[image]

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error stems from your `app` module. You have to set up Java 8 for each separate module. Go to **File** > **Project Structure** and update it from the **Properties** tab for that module or make sure you have added the `compileOptions` snippet to the correct `build.gradle` file of your `app` module.

If there are further modules, make sure they are set up for Java 8, before using Java 8 functionality.

For full reference, see [the official Android Java 8 Support Page](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support).

Comment: Hi, this is my Project Structure: https://imgur.com/a/aUSrZ91, I think all is set. But build still failed. Let me know if anything else is missing.

Comment: Try cleaning the project. Seems like an Android Studio issue.

Comment: done cleaning, upgraded android studio to latest version, but still no luck, build still failed

Comment: Finally, I got this fixed. There is one module I forgot to update. Now is fixed!. Thanks

Comment: Adding source in pom file->maven-compiler-dependency worked for me -   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6svfLUxK2nA